# How to change tag in xml with shell script

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="in.rakshanshetty.ionic" version="bar">
  <name>ionic test</name>
  <description>An awesome my app</description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>

</widget>
```

How to change author email, href and content inside it with xmlstarlet

Comment: You need to add here what you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit -N x='http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets' \
                --update "//x:widget/x:author/@email" --value "foo@example.com" \
                --update "//x:widget/x:author/@href"  --value "http://www.example.com" \
                --update "//x:widget/x:author"        --value "foo" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" id="in.rakshanshetty.ionic" version="bar">
  <name>ionic test</name>
  <description>An awesome my app</description>
  <author email="foo@example.com" href="http://www.example.com">foo</author>
</widget>
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option -L.